# Sending emails from within Azure SQL Elastic Jobs steps

Tags: azure-sql-database

In Azure Elastic Jobs (preview) I am trying to find a way to send an email from within T_SQL in one of the job steps as msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail is not available in elastic Jobs. I have done some research and it appears there is no native support that i can find for achieving this and the only suggestion I have found so far is saving the jobs output to a table and then using something else (like PowerShell) to send the actual email.

Here is a [link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/automate-and-send-alerts-for-elastic-jobs-failures/ba-p/1981457) to an article explaining one way of achieving this and another here [link](https://www.sqlshack.com/configuring-email-notifications-in-azure-sql-database/).

Has anyone found a better solution to this?

Comment: Azure SQL database doesn't support `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail`. That's why we must use other tools like PowerShell or logic app. Just for now, these are the solutions we only can find per our experience. I afraid to say, there won't a better solution for now.

Comment: Hi @hamish, do you have any other concerns? May I post it as answer?

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL database doesn't support [msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). That's why we must use other tools like PowerShell or logic app. Just for now, these are the solutions we can find and  there isn't a better solution for now.

If you want use this feature, may you can choose Azure SQL managed instance or SQL Server in VMs.

HTH.